# What's the best way to set all elements of array to a value?

Tags: c

I have an array of ints and I'd like to set all values in the array to 'x' everytime a function is called.

I've looked at memset but that would only work for an array of bytes I think.

I could do the obvious for loop, but I'm guessing there is a standard lib function out there that will accomplish this better. Anyone know?

Comment: A loop is the best choice.

Comment: `memset` is probably just a loop internally, so your loop will be as good.

Comment: In C a loop is the way to do it. In C++ there's `std::fill` if you can use it.

Comment: @CarlNorum A very fancy loop

Comment: If 'x' is a char you can do `memset(array,'x',sizeof(array))`

Comment: @CarlNorum Sorry, I misread your comment :-)

Comment: @JesusRamos, glibc's `memset` is pretty straightforward.  It has little bit of alignment and a some loop unrolling, but I don't know about "very fancy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop it, pretty much.  Or `memset` to 0, if you know the value is zero (similar for other values for which you have knowledge of the bit representation).  There won't be a standard lib solution, since the standard lib can't know of particular user types.

Comment: Setting memset to zero is kind of counterproductive because `int myArray[80] = {0}` would initialise all array elements to zero.

Comment: @Rapptz: only upon definition.  Subsequent fills require memset.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on an x86 system, you can use some assembly for this.  For instance, in gcc:

```
    __asm__(
            "rep stosb"
            : "=a"('x'), "=c"(count), "=D"(array)
           );
```

Should do the trick.

`rep stosb` takes the value in `AL` and assigns it to consecutive memory locations pointed to by `ES:EDI`.  The number of the locations is specified in `ECX`.

As an aside, in recent processors [Intel has made many efforts to improve the performance of `MOVSB` and `STOSB`](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Inside-the-Intel-Ivy-Bridge-Microarchitecture/1397/), so this is a good way to go about it.

Comment: Please _don't_ add assembly hacks! What you write is just `memset(3)`, and the compiler (at least GCC) will do that on its own for `memset` (check the generated assembly if you don't believe me). Result: A harder to understand, non-portable program for _no_ gain (and possibly much worse than what the compiler does).

Comment: @vonbrand: you're probably right. You know what they say, when all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.  I'm more familiar with x86 assembly than with C, and when I was trying to remember about `memset`, I couldn't, but I *was* able to remember `STOSB`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my case im writing code that has to be portable to several processors so I cant use this, but its still a nice to learn some new x86 asm.thanks!

Comment: `"=a"('x')` should be in the input section (a non-lvalue also cannot be an output). Writing `+c` and `+D` is a bit safer so that the compiler cannot change the value of the tied variables upon entry to the `asm` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `memset` and looping (which are both `O(n)` time), **it can be actually done in `O(1)`** - but at the cost of triple the amount of memory, and more expensive look ups later on.

[This article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time/) describes how it can be done.

The idea is to maintain additional stack (logically, implemented as array+ pointer to top) and array, the additional array will indicate when it was first initialized (a number from 0 to n) and the stack will indicate which elements were already modified.

When you access `array[i]`, if `stack[additionalArray[i]] == i && i < top` the value of the array is `array[i]`. Otherwise - it is the "initialized" value.

When doing `array[i] = x`, if it was not initialized yet (as seen before), you should set `additionalArray[i] = stack[top]` and increase `top`.

This results in `O(1)` initialization, but as said it requires additional memory and each access is more expansive.

Answer (score 0):

Below logic will helps you.

```
...
int a[100] = {0};
int b = 5;
memset_ex(a, 100, &b, sizeof(int));
...

memset_ex(void *buf, int buf_size, void *value, int size_of_type)
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i <= (buf_size - size_of_type); i +=size_of_type)
    {
        memcpy((buf + i), value, size_of_type);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this be better than `for(i=0;i<N;i++) a[i]=5;` ?; I could understand a trick doing _overlapping_ memcpy from a[0]=b; memcpy(a+1,a,sizeof(int)*(n-1)); // but even in this case one should optimize the overlap to be an exact length of a cache line.